# from complex function to a series

Tags: complex, series-expansion

How can I express this complex function as a series?

```
Log[
 (1 - E^((I Pi (1 - a))/(b - a)) z)/
 (1 - E^(-((I Pi (1 - a))/(b - a))) z)
]
```

Where `z` is the complex number, `a` and `b` are real numbers, `a < 1` and `b > 1`.

Comment: After tidying up your expression and using `FullSimplify` on it, I get zero. Is that what you expected?

Comment: Its the Log of thing/thing, and Log[1]=0. So the series is pretty straightforward!

Comment: sorry I edited the function right now

Comment: `SeriesCoefficient[
  Log[(1 - E^((I Pi (1 - a))/(b - a)) z)/(1 - 
      E^(-((I Pi (1 - a))/(b - a))) z)], {z, 0, n}] // FullSimplify`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us define

```
   tt=Log[(1 - E^((I Pi (1 - a))/(b - a)) z)/(1 - E^(-((I Pi (1 - a))/(b - a))) z)];
```

Then, in order to get the Series expansion coefficient to any order

```
   coef= SeriesCoefficient[tt, {z, 0, n}] // FullSimplify
```

(* -((2 I sin((π (a-1) n)/(a-b)))/n)   *)

Indeed

```
  tt2=Sum[coef[[1, 1, 1]] z^n, {n,1, Infinity}]-tt
```

is null.

If you want to check

```
    Series[tt2, {z, 0, 15}]
```

(* O[z^16] *) for instance.

Note that you could do the Taylor expansion by hand

```
 Table[1/n! D[tt, {z, n}] /. z -> 0 // 
 FullSimplify[#, Assumptions -> {a < 1, b > 1}] & // Together, {n, 
 1, 5}]//TableForm
```

and identify the prefactor of `Sin[n(a-1)π/(a-b)]` as `-2I/n`